# How to set up a hierarchy via Fluent API in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-mapping

I have a hierarchy of employees, which have boss and subordinates.

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Job { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Boss { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to configure it as follows:

```
internal class EmployeeConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
  public EmployeeConfiguracao()
  {
    HasOptional(p => p.Boss).WithMany(p => p.Subordinates).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  }
}
```

But the result of `Add-Migration Init`
Note that Boss is not-null but the is optional (president has no boss)

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Employees",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 90),
            Job = c.String(),
            Boss_Id = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Employees", t => t.Boss_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Boss_Id);
```

How to set up this hierarchy so that it can be employed without boss (as President)

Comment: Your hierarchy already works this way. Boss_Id is a nullable key, so you don't have to have a boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Boss should be nullable it should be defined like this:

```
Boss_Id = c.Int(nullable: false)
```

If it is setup like this:

```
Boss_Id = c.Int()
```

then default value for nullable will be used which is true, so it is as you wanted it to be.

Comment: Are you saying that the way it is setup, works? with `Boss_Id = c.Int()`

Comment: Yes, it will generate nullable int column in table in db.

Comment: strange `Boss_Id = c.Int(nullable: true)` is same that `Boss_Id = c.Int()`